# Using Msp430G2 UART for programming HM-10 & ZS-040 on linux

Tags: bluetooth, linux

I want to pair Bluetooth with computer. I want to sent some data and plot them over Bluetooth. But following two not giving any response on serial connection.

I need to connect Bluetooth module which [HM-10 115200](https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-EXP430G2) or [ZS-040](https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-EXP430G2)[HC-05] for displaying serial data, so I ONLY use [MSP](https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-EXP430G2) for UART connection for pairing commands `AT` and `AT+INIT\r\n` commands.

I can't get any answer from it! But, It should. I can't and don't understand why?

Here some what I did for connection

```
[20619.441479] usb 3-3.2: Manufacturer: Texas Instruments
[20619.441482] usb 3-3.2: SerialNumber: ***************
[20619.445638] cdc_acm 3-3.2:1.0: ttyACM1: USB ACM device
[20619.446257] cdc_acm 3-3.2:1.2: ttyACM2: USB ACM device
[20982.378808] usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 23
[20991.088759] usb 3-2: new full-speed USB device number 26 using xhci_hcd
[20991.252134] usb 3-2: New USB de...nd, idVendor=0**1, idProduct=f**2, bcdDevice= 1.05
```

```
ls -l /dev/ttyACM*
crw-rw-rw- 1 root uucp 166, 0 Jun 25 18:58 /dev/ttyACM0
```

Then I gave some permissions

```
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyS4
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM1
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyACM0
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyS4
```

```
ls -l /dev/tty*
crw--w---- 1 root tty    4,  9 Jun 24 12:07 /dev/tty9
crw-rw-rw- 1 root uucp 166,  0 Jun 24 18:29 /dev/ttyACM0
crw-rw---- 1 root uucp   4, 95 Jun 24 12:07 /dev/ttyS31
crw-rw-rw- 1 root uucp   4, 68 Jun 24 18:40 /dev/ttyS4
crw-rw---- 1 root uucp   4, 69 Jun 24 12:07 /dev/ttyS5
```

I tried with `screen` command and over `energia` serial console
I connect but can't receive any response

#### Connection

| MSPBoard side | BT Module |
| --- | --- |
| VCC 3V | VCC |
| GND | GND |
| TX | RX |
| RX | TX |

I tried two of Bluetooth module but can't get any response on `9600` or `115200` via `energia serial` and

`sudo screen /dev/ttyS4 9600` or `sudo screen /dev/ttyACM0 9600` commands terminal  freezing sometimes barely gives `?`

#### SIMPLE SCHEMATIC

1. Ripped all [Msp430G2](https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-EXP430G2)'s all jumper then connected just `RX & TX`.
2. Supplied Bluetooth module `VCC->3.3V[HC-05 5V]`, `GND->GND` pins connected different stable psu then `RX` and `TX` connected reversely to each other.(just tried two model for ensuring)

```
   MSP430G2 Lauchpad  |             
   debugger           |                    Bluetoth module
    _____________________________________________________________________
   |                  |                   ______________________        |      
   |                 o|o Test           o|  EN                  |       |          
   |                 o|o RESET      3.3Vo|  VCC                 |       |         
   |           - - - o|o RX         GND o|  GND    HM-10        |       |          
   |           |  |- o|o TX    -------- o|  TXD     &           |       |           
   |           |  |  o|o VCC   |    ----o|  RXD    ZS-040       |       |    
   |           |  |---|--------|----|   o|  STATE               |       |      
   |           |______|________|          -----------------------       |                
   |                  |                                                 |
   |                  |                                                 |
   |                  |                                                 |
   |---               |                                                 |
   |usb|              |                                                 |
   |---               |                                                 |
   ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   Usb to computer(ofcourse)
```

Comment: It sounds like there are some level conversion and inversions that may not be there in the hardware. Post a schematic, not a frizzy thing showing your system and include links to technical information on the hardware devices.

Comment: @Gil I did. I hope looks better now

Comment: Start by connecting RX to TX on the USB/serial board and see if what you type is echoed back, and at what speed(s) this works (if it does), using which device, and so on. Once you have confirmation this works, you can connect the BT module. You may want to check the speed that module supports (and if that matches the MSP’s speed), the power and logic levels (voltages) and possibly if RX/TX actually need to be crossed (some devices have RX/TX labelled from the MCU perspective, not their own, so RX-RX and TX-TX.

Comment: Unless I am reading your question wrong one is 5V and the other is 3.3V, you need a level translator. using resistor dividers is at best extremely shaky.

Comment: @jcaron you're right, this [msp430 board](https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-EXP430G2) device I think doesn't [support](https://e2e.ti.com/support/interface-group/interface/f/interface-forum/666506/linux-msp430g2553-uart-communication-using-minicom) Linux. But  [MspEXP430F5529LP](https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-EXP430F5529LP) good echoing on `/dev/ttyACM1` port. This board looks good echoing every baud rate between `300-2000000 baud` this problem's first part solved.

Comment: @Gil I prefer use [ MspEXP430F5529LP](https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-EXP430F5529LP) this has two But I can't manage get any answer yet from those two BL module yet(reversing TX-TX include).

Answer (score 0):

There is wrong point using this board on Linux and Mac clearly described [here](https://e2e.ti.com/support/interface-group/interface/f/interface-forum/666506/linux-msp430g2553-uart-communication-using-minicom)

[NOTE: eZ430-tools are not supported on USB3.0 ports. eZ430 tools are supported on Windows
operating systems only—Linux and OS X are not supported.](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau647o/slau647o.pdf?ts=1646648153167&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)